# Adjust last operarion menu does not work with newly made mesh and mesh is placed twice

Tags: python

I made a little script that makes a plane with thickness
when i add the mesh to my model it places 2 meshes instead of 1

For 1 of the 2 meshes the ALO menu works but for the second one not
Can someone help me and tell me what i did wrong?

This is the code i use

```
    bl_info = {
    "name": "Test object",
    "author": "DGRL",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 1),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > DGRL",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}

import bpy
import bmesh
import mathutils
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add



def add_object(self, context):


    verts = [(1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 0.9, 0), (-0.25, 0.9, 0),] 


    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh") 
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new("MyObject", mesh)

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj) 
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj 
    bpy.context.active_object.select_set(state=True)

    mesh = bpy.context.object.data
    bm = bmesh.new()

    for v in verts:
        bm.verts.new(v) 

    bm.faces.new(bm.verts)
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)  
    bm.free()


    **object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)**  *<-- THIS LINE MAKES A SECOND BMESH BUT WITHOUT THERE IS NO ADJUST LAST OPERATION MENU!*



class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    def execute(self, context):

        add_object(self, context)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="Add Object",
        icon='PLUGIN')

def add_object_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/"
    url_manual_mapping = (
        ("bpy.ops.mesh.add_object", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
    )
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.unregister_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: The *Adjust Last Operation* panel will only be for the *last operation*. If you're adding multiple objects it will only be for the most recent one.

Comment: Yes i know 
the issue here is that i dont want to add 2 meshes but only 1

Comment: Please test the script and see what happens

Comment: @DRGL with the approach you're using, there's no need for the `object_data_add` since you've already created and linked the object with its mesh data.

Comment: How can i get the ALO menu in my script to work with the mesh i created?
The ALO menu pops up but does not work at all

Comment: You need an operator that has properties which can be adjusted. Currently you're adding the object at a fixed location with fixed vertex positions.

Comment: I dont get it tbh
When i use object_data_add the location and rotation and align is just working fine on the second mesh that is placed ( let me be clear i want only 1 mesh to be placed)
Why is it not working on the mesh i created? Im not talking about scaling but the 3 basic properties (location , rotation and align)

Comment: Didn't we already solve that 2 weeks ago: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160952/31447 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link the adjust last operation menu to object? Blender 2.80 - 2.81](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160946/how-to-link-the-adjust-last-operation-menu-to-object-blender-2-80-2-81)

Comment: @brockmann
No that was something different
In that question the script was made using bpy.ops 
Ive been told to use bmesh instead of bpy.ops and create new meshes 
seems to be fun learning bmesh bit its a whole different thing

Thanks for you help back then. learned a lot from it

Comment: I recommended creating and manipulating meshes using ` bmesh` over the use of  `bpy.ops.mesh...` operators in edit mode in particular.  Unfortunately since I only created the meshes, it gave the impression nothing was happening. [Made edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161512/15543)  Please take some time to digest the changes made in answer below and question above, eg `mesh = bpy.context.object.data`  vs `mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh") `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question COde:**

- Makes a new mesh.
- Makes a new object that links to new empty mesh
- Links object to collection makes it active and selected
- Links the empty mesh to object again (new object is now context)
- Makes the bmesh and loads into mesh

Makes the mesh ok and adds a new object linked to that mesh to scene collections Ok... but it is not being transformed / aligned at all.

> I dont get it tbh When i use object_data_add the location and rotation
>   and align is just working fine on the second mesh that is placed ( let
>   me be clear i want only 1 mesh to be placed) Why is it not working on
>   the mesh i created? Im not talking about scaling but the 3 basic
>   properties (location , rotation and align)

Because that is being done for you by the imported

**`AddObjectHelper` and `object_data_add`**

The function `object_data_add` is designed for use in conjunction with the `AddObjectHelper` class.   It creates a new object, linked to the `context` collection objects,  linked to our new  `mesh`, transformed via location, rotation and align properties of the `operator`.

That is why it is passed `(context, mesh, operator=self)` , eg if the new object is  `ob`  the code of `object_data_add(...)` could include

```
ob.data = mesh
ob.location = operator.location
```

to position the object.  *The code is available to peruse*  *`2.8x/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/object_utils.py`*

**Changes**

- Conformed to operator naming standard
- Removed un-needed imports
- Removed un-needed documentation links
- Changed around the methodology somewhat. The function
  `add_plane_mesh()` takes no argument and returns a mesh, regardless
  of operator or context.  This makes it very re-usable, for example if
  addon is in a folder named "test_addon" could

  ```
     from test_addon import add_plane_object
  ```

  to use elsewhere.  Moved `object_data_add(...)` into the operator's execute method conveniently with `self` and `context` as arguments.

Amended question code.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Test object",
    "author": "DGRL",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 1),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > DGRL",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}

import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add


def add_plane_mesh():

    verts = [(1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 0.9, 0), (-0.25, 0.9, 0),] 

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh") 
    bm = bmesh.new()

    bm.faces.new(bm.verts.new(v) for v in verts)
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)  
    bm.free()
    return mesh

class MESH_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object" 
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    def execute(self, context):
        object_data_add(
                context, 
                add_plane_mesh(), 
                operator=self)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        MESH_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="Add Object",
        icon='PLUGIN')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_add_object)        
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_add_object)        
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2):

*This was a quick answer to the user's question, however batFINGER's answer provides more details on how to improve the add-on. It also addresses other issues such as the architecture/structure, imports and the naming convention.*

---

If you want to use `object_data_add()` from `bpy_extras.object_utils` then remove the object creation and linking to the scene from `add_object`.

```
def add_object(self, context):

    verts = [(1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 0.9, 0), (-0.25, 0.9, 0),] 

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh") 

    bm = bmesh.new()

    for v in verts:
        bm.verts.new(v) 

    bm.faces.new(bm.verts)
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)  
    bm.free()

    object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)
```

Comment: This is what i meant @Robert 
Thanks again for your lessons and help

Appriciate it guys