# Select edge loop of mesh using python

Tags: python

I would like to select an edge loop on the beginning or end of a bmesh

The selection could be based on height (z axis) and width / depth (X / Y axis)

I made the outer and the inner square with `bmesh.ops.create_grid`.

I found this article but it does not solve my question

[Python select specific edge loop based on diameter and height](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161470/python-select-specific-edge-loop-based-on-diameter-and-height)

I also tried to select vertices using this code

```
my_verts = [v for v in bm.verts if (50 / 1000) <= v.co.z <= (101 / 1000)]
my_verts1 = [v for v in my_verts if (-5.01 / 1000) <= v.co.x <= (5.01 / 1000)]
my_verts1 = [v for v in my_verts if (-5.01/ 1000) <= v.co.y <= (5.01  / 1000)]
```

but this method is not really precise and when using vert.link_edges from the selected verts I also get edges that I don't need.

See screenshot 
I would like to be able to select the inner edge loop or the outer (Not combined)

[image]

After the bevel is done the original edges are dead so i need to make a new selection 
The return data of the bevel command contains the edges at the bottom as well as the top and in between.

So to make 1 long question short.

How can I get the edge loops (top or bottom) of the inner grid as well as the edges of the outer grid?

As extra it would be nice to have the edges between the bottom and the top

Comment: Please don't [delete and re-ask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162456/select-edge-loop-of-mesh-using-python) the same question to bump it.  _"Anyone who wants to help me with this question?"_  Definitely not me. i) I believe my  [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161512/15543) to the linked question goes a long way to answering this.  Add the grid, bevel it,  (as opposed to add circle or cylinder) then extrude.  Seems to be an agenda to posting it.

Comment: @batFINGER I would not ask this if your answer would help me. It does not solve my question

Comment: ii) [glib comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161903/python-draw-2-vertices-under-specified-angle-edit#comment274202_161991) iii) failure to post minimal working code, as you been requested to do by others too,  which without  can lead to [this bs.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162203/merge-vertices-at-center-bmesh#comment274410_162208)

Comment: I already posted minimal working code @batFINGER
Please read the post before commenting failure before posting

And why don't you want to help? Your member here to help others right

Comment: I am, but at my choosing.  I enjoy answering questions.  I believe I have helped a lot of people with my answers. There is no script in question that can be  run that adds the model as demonstrated in question. (aka minimal working code)  Read your comments [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162203/merge-vertices-at-center-bmesh#comment274410_162208)  re reading post first and commenting failure,  ... what is more important, _seems_ telling me I'm wrong, over an answer.  Anyhoo takes the fun out of it.

Comment: Got it  :-)
I will make a new post and post a general template (something every coder should have). this template can be used to quickly reproduce questions asked and at least generate an answer. Why when asking a question does the source code needs to be given away? that's really weird and sometimes due to CR or other stuff not even possible.
Anyway Thanks for your time so far